# Running service after application close

Tags: android, service

My application need to run service in background even if user closed the app.
But, when I closed my app, the service stop and restart. So, all variables who are in the service are reset.

After search on google, I have found that :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

But it do not work. My service is reset.

Comment: use **[startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)**

Comment: Yes, but this need API 26 minimum

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to consider the fact that If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on running background services when the app itself is not in the foreground. In most cases like this, your app should use a scheduled job instead. You can read more on this link:
[Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks.
So how can I keep alive my service even if user closed app ?

Comment: Then it depends on the role of your service. What the purpose of your service?

Comment: My service do calcul on variables then send to some activities variable in broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your service to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, I have add my service in Manifest. My service run but reset when I closed my app